# How can i make the dropdown the same size as button (width)

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown and a button, how would I go on about making the dropdown the same size as the button?

```css
:root {
  --navbarbgc: rgb(83, 79, 79);
  --dropwidth: 100px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: var(--navbarbgc);
}

.navbar>ul>li>button {
  width: var(--dropwidth);
}

#navdrop {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: var(--navbarbgc);
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><button id="navdropbutton">Dropdown</button>
      <ul id="navdrop">
        <li>Option1</li>
        <li>Option2</li>
        <li>Option3</li>
        <li>Option4</li>
        <li>Option5</li>
        <li>Option6</li>
        <li>Option7</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I tried making a variable and then putting the same size to them but that didn't work.

Comment: A small tip I used (may not be the most efficient way) but I used to use inspect elements in chrome and select the item that I want to resize. From there I can either edit the css or use `style=" "`

Comment: @GamzXT Had a look at the jsFiddle. From the CSS I can see they are different sizes due to the `padding-inline-start` on the `<ul>` tag. You could change this and then as you said created a variable of the same size and apply it both to the button and dropdown items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did

Added class `button-li` to the `li` element which has `button`

And added this css

```
#navdrop {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: var(--navbarbgc);
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.button-li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vsm15jok/

Answer (score 1):

Here I gave **button** **width** of **100px**, removed **padding** from **#navdrop** and gave **width** of **100px** to **#navdrop** (same as button) then I just centered the text using **text-align**. you should **NOT** be using **justify-content** because it does nothing for you right now. use **justify-content** with Flex

```
#navdrop {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: var(--navbarbgc);
    width: 100px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
#navdropbutton {
  width: 100px;  
}
```

**Fiddle**: 
https://jsfiddle.net/10c2axds/1/

Answer (score 0):

you can add w-100 to the dropdown-menu class part

```
<div class="dropdown" style="margin-right: 5px;width: 23%;">
  <button class="btn btn-block btn-warning dropdown-toggle btn-lg" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    OPERAZIONI
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu w-100" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
<button type="button" class=" dropdown-item border border-warning rounded">
    <a class="bottonePreferenze" data-link="/pg/ac_Operazione" href="/pg/ac_Operazione">
          <i class="fa fa-cube fa-2x"></i>
    <span>ANAGRAFICA OPERAZIONI</span>
    </a></button>
  </div>
</div>
```